# Matching keywords from text file against MySql field to find number of occurrences

Tags: mysql

I have a text file with 1000 keywords I would like to match against a MySql database to find the number of occurrences for each keyword in my database.

Here's how I find matches for a single word:
    `SELECT (SELECT COUNT(description) FROM items WHERE (description LIKE '%keyword%')) AS MatchingWord`

Is there a way to do the same with all the 1000 words in the txt file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:

```
SELECT `description`, COUNT(`description`) FROM `items` WHERE `description` IN ("keyword1","...","keyword1000") GROUP BY `description`
```

The key ingredient here is the `IN` element which allows to specifiy several items for the same filtered column in a `WHERE` command.

Can you get the 1000 items into a string with each item delimited by quotes (") and a comma (,)? If yes, paste that into the `IN` command.

Caveat: I have not tried this with 1000 keywords before. You might run into a performance issue or hit your SQL server's query length limit. If that happens, research the `max_allowed_packet` setting or consider splitting your query into several smaller queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can either bind your query and then run it 1000 times:

Or you can load your 1000 words into a table and run a JOIN query:

```
$sql = '';
$text = file_get_contents('keywords.txt');
foreach (explode($text, PHP_EOL) as $keyword)
    $sql .= "INSERT INTO tmpText (keyword) VALUES ('$keyword'); ";
if (mysqli_multi_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "New records created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}
// Now run this query:
//   SELECT keyword, COUNT(description) AS Matches 
//   FROM tmpText, items 
//   WHERE  description LIKE CONCAT('%',keyword,'%')
//   GROUP BY keyword
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first import all keywords into a column of a table, and then match the columns of these two tables with each other.

First import file keywords into table :

```
   LOAD DATA INFILE 'mydata.txt' INTO TABLE table_mydata
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ''
   LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' (column_name);
```

Now, match columns of both the tables like this :

```
  SELECT
  i.description,
  count(m.column_name)
  FROM items i
  JOIN table_mydata m
  ON i.description LIKE CONCAT('%', m.column_name, '%')
  group by i.description;
```